# A distance function which scales with the value size

Tags: machine-learning

This is a math question related to machine learning.

I have a data set I want to cluster and to do this I want to define a bespoke distance  function.   My understanding of the data is that the distance between  numerical values depends on the scale. That is 9 is not very close to 10 but 900 is very close to 901.

Is there a natural mathematical distance function (or transformation) that encapsulates this intuition? Ideally it would be parameterized so I can grid search to find good distance functions.

Answer (score 0):

you could define a relative measure of distance:
D = V1 / V2 - 1
Using this,
D = 9 / 10 -1 = -0.1 , that is, 9 is 10% lesser than 10.
Another example,
D = 201 / 200 -1 = 0.005 , that is, 201 is 5% bigger than 200.
Obviously this definition doesn't work if your reference V2 is zero.

Comment: Correcting a mistake: "... 201 is 0,5% bigger than 200."

Comment: Thank you. How could you parameterize this?

Comment: What do you mean by parametrize?

Comment: I just meant change how much scale affects the answer.  For example make 9 relatively closer to 10  or further away.